# Artifactory AQL Display Checksums

Tags: artifactory, artifactory-query-lang

How can I include the **Checksums** for an item found with an `AQL query`?

By adding this `include` statement:

```
items.find( ... )
.include("name","checksums")
```

AQL returns the below error:

> it looks like there is syntax error near the following sub-query:
>   checksums

Answer (score 2):

You need to include the 'actual_sha1' instead of the "checksums" that will list the artifact sha1.